# How to update all objects of array based on another array element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Suppose I have two array of same object type, Now I want to update all the elements of first array based on some key of another array. `I want to update isSelected to true if myArray id ,matches with testArray id`.
I can ietrate through myArray using for loop and check every id which is found in the testArray and based on that index isSelected value can be updated. But I am wondering if I can use higher order function like `contains` or `filter` for this use case.

```
class MyObject
{
    var id: Int
    var isSelected:Bool?
    var value: String
}

var myArray = [{id: 1, isSelected: nil, value: abcd}, {id: 2, 
isSelected: nil, value: xyz}, {id: 3, isSelected: nil, value: hghghg} ]

var testArray = [{id: 1, isSelected: nil, value: abcd}, {id: 2, 
isSelected: nil, value: xyz}]

let resultArray = [{id: 1, isSelected: true, value: abcd}, {id: 2, 
isSelected: true, value: xyz}, {id: 3, isSelected: nil, value: hghghg}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
let testArrIds = testArray.map { $0.id }
myArray.forEach { $0.isSelected =  testArrIds.contains($0.id) ? true : $0.isSelected  }
```

It can be 1 line but i don't want to map the ids every loop of forEach as it would be expensive

```
myArray.forEach { $0.isSelected =  testArray.map { $0.id }.contains($0.id) ? true : $0.isSelected  }
```

Comment: Two line solution is perfect, thanks Mr Khan :) can you please explain this `? true : $0.isSelected `

Comment: @Xcoder don't forget to add an init to your class or make all vars optional

Comment: read section **Ternary Conditional Operator** in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html

Comment: Yes, I have already added the init, hanks for pointing it out btw.

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes to your class and arrays to make the code work

```
class MyObject: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Int
    var isSelected:Bool?
    var value: String

    var description: String {
        return "\(id) \(value) \(isSelected ?? false)"
    }

    init(id: Int, value: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
}

var myArray = [MyObject(id: 1, value: "abcd"), MyObject(id: 2, value: "xyz"), MyObject(id: 3, value: "hghghg") ]

var testArray = [MyObject(id: 1, value: "abcd"), MyObject(id: 2, value: "xyz")]

testArray.forEach( { myObject in
    if let first = myArray.first(where: { $0.id == myObject.id }) {
        first.isSelected = true
    }
})

print(myArray)
```

> [1 abcd true, 2 xyz true, 3 hghghg false]

Answer (score 0):

the above solution works well for class objects but not for structs, we can do it the following way for structs if someone is specifically looking for that like me.

```
struct Tag {
    let title: String
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}

let fetched = array of tags fetched from server
let current = array of currently selected tags
```

Now we want to update the tags from server to get selected using currently selected tags

```
let updatedTags = fetched.map { fetchedTag in
    var updatedTag = fetchedTag
    if current.map({ $0.title }).contains(updatedTag.title) {
        updatedTag.isSelected = true
    }
    return updatedTag
 }
```