# I have two array. How Can I change different value in Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, favorites

I'm sending only items with `isSelected = true` into `favCountries`.
There are all the countries that came from the service in `countries`.
I want to compare the `countries` coming from the service with `favCountries` and make `isSelected = true` in the countries array for countries with the same `code` and the values that are isSelected = true in favCountries.

If the code in the `favCountries` array and the `code` in the `countries` array match, I want to make the item value in the `countries` array `isSelected = true`

I am using this model.

```
public struct CountryData: Codable {
  public let code: String?
  public let currencyCodes: [String]?
  public let name: String?
  public let wikiDataID: String?
  public var isSelected: Bool = false
}

var favCountries: [CountryData]
var countries: [CountryData]
```

Comment: Not sure what is your question but I guess `let favCountries = countries.filter(\.isSelected)
`

Comment: no sir. isSelected property does not come from the service. I added this myself.
Sorry. I know little English.

Comment: If you add some example and the expected result would be much easier to help you

Comment: you have to use class instead struct, because the struct is value type.

Comment: @cristian_064 That is not correct, a struct works fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564856/how-to-update-all-objects-of-array-based-on-another-array-element/64137857

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you are asking again. But if I understood correctly make your `CountryData` conform to `Equatable`, iterate your countries indices and if `favCountries` contains the current element change the countries `isSelected` property to `true`:

---

```
extension CountryData: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.name == rhs.name // match the appropriate properties
    }
}
```

---

```
countries.indices.forEach { index in
    if favCountries.contains(countries[index]) {
        countries[index].isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: like this sir. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53564856/how-to-update-all-objects-of-array-based-on-another-array-element/64137857

Comment: thank you sir. This code is success for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the question correctly,

1. you want to loop through `var favCountries: [CountryData]` and `var countries: [CountryData].code`
2. IF IN your loop(s) you the condition where `favCountries[$0]` == `countries[$0].code` IS TRUE, THEN you want to set $0.isSelected to TRUE.

My approach in pseudo code:

You can loop through one array and check if each objects code exists in the other array and then if it does exist, set your isSelected value to true.

Assuming that both [CountryData] arrays are even you could try something like this:

```
FOR EACH country in CountryData {
  if let hasMatch = countries.contains({where: country.code == $0.code}) {
    country.isSelected = true
   
}
```

Good luck.

Let me know if this helps!